# How to add a text input field along with radio input button in Google Form?

Tags: google-forms

I am creating a Google Doc Form for a company's internal survey. One question is like: 'Do you have a Dental School Program by Another company or organisation, if yes What?' How can I add a text input field along with the radio input field?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe set your first question as `Multiple choice` and check `Go to page based on answer`. Offer `No` with `Continue to page 2` and `Yes` with `Go to page 3`, with the first question on page 3 being something like "Please provide details of your existing Dental school Program" and a `Paragraph text` Question Type.